# Make systemd service understand change in configuration file

Tags: systemd

I have a `systemd` service that more or less is like this:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/binary subcommand
User=my-user
Group=my-group
EnvironmentFile=/etc/my-service/config
```

I am changing the contents of `/etc/my-service/config`

Should I run `daemon-reload` or just reload the service?

Note that I don't have an `ExecReload` directive on my unit file; does this affect the `systemctl reload my-service`'s behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither `daemon-reload` nor `reload` will cause `EnvironmentFile=` to be read by your main process.

The man page says files listed with `EnvironmentFile=` will be read shortly before the process is executed.

- This suggests `start` or `restart` will cause the file to be read.  That's because `start` or `restart` will execute the process.
- This also suggests `daemon-reload` will have no effect because `daemon-reload` does not `start` or `restart` the unit.
- This additionally suggests `reload` will have no effect because `reload` does not create the main process.  It only gives an opportunity to send a signal to the main process to reload its configuration.  This is especially true if you have no `ExecReload=` defined.

---

### A supporting experiment

```
$ systemctl --user cat env.service
# /home/stew/.config/systemd/user/env.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "while true; do sleep 1; echo $EXAMPLE_ENV; done"
EnvironmentFile=%h/env

$ cat ~/env
EXAMPLE_ENV="Hi"

$ systemctl --user start env.service
```

Then I monitor the journal during the operations:

```
$ journalctl --user -u env.service -f
...
Feb 11 15:35:47 stewbian systemd[1108]: Started env.service.
Feb 11 15:35:48 stewbian bash[911848]: Hi
Feb 11 15:35:49 stewbian bash[911848]: Hi
```

Then I change the environment file and see no change in the output

```
$ sed -i -e 's/Hi/Yo/' ~/env
...
Feb 11 15:37:13 stewbian bash[911848]: Hi
Feb 11 15:37:14 stewbian bash[911848]: Hi
Feb 11 15:37:15 stewbian bash[911848]: Hi
```

Then I try a `systemctl reload` and see no change in the output:

```
$ systemctl --user reload env.service
Failed to reload env.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit env.service.
...
Feb 11 15:38:14 stewbian bash[911848]: Hi
Feb 11 15:38:15 stewbian bash[911848]: Hi
```

Then I try a `daemon-reload` and see no change in the output:

```
$ systemctl --user daemon-reload
...
Feb 11 15:38:46 stewbian bash[911848]: Hi
Feb 11 15:38:47 stewbian bash[911848]: Hi
```

So then I try a restart and see the change.

```
$ systemctl --user restart env.service
...
Feb 11 15:39:29 stewbian bash[911848]: Hi
Feb 11 15:39:30 stewbian bash[911848]: Hi
Feb 11 15:39:30 stewbian systemd[1108]: Stopping env.service...
Feb 11 15:39:30 stewbian systemd[1108]: Stopped env.service.
Feb 11 15:39:30 stewbian systemd[1108]: Started env.service.
Feb 11 15:39:31 stewbian bash[912531]: Yo
Feb 11 15:39:32 stewbian bash[912531]: Yo
```

One interesting thing is adding `ExecReload=/bin/bash -c 'echo $EXAMPLE_ENV` to the unit.  In that case I get this:

```
Feb 11 15:58:24 stewbian bash[914611]: Hi
Feb 11 15:58:25 stewbian bash[914611]: Hi
Feb 11 15:58:26 stewbian systemd[1108]: Reloading env.service...
Feb 11 15:58:26 stewbian bash[914640]: Yo
Feb 11 15:58:26 stewbian systemd[1108]: Reloaded env.service.
Feb 11 15:58:26 stewbian bash[914611]: Hi
Feb 11 15:58:27 stewbian bash[914611]: Hi
```

So here you can see `systemd` does read `EnvironmentFile=` before starting the `ExecReload=`, but only passes the new environment to the new process.  It does not change the environment of existing processes.

I retried this by putting that `bash` stuff in a separate script to ensure systemd environment variable substitution didn't affect anything during the parsing of the `Exec*=` lines... Same result.

---

### Supporting documentation

`man systemd.exec`:

```
EnvironmentFile=
   ...         
   The files listed with this directive will be read shortly before
   the process is executed (more specifically, after all processes
   from a previous unit state terminated. This means you can
   generate these files in one unit state, and read it with this
   option in the next. The files are read from the file system of
   the service manager, before any file system changes like bind
   mounts take place).
```

`man systemctl`:

```
   reload PATTERN...
       Asks all units listed on the command line to reload their
       configuration. Note that this will reload the service-specific
       configuration, not the unit configuration file of systemd. If you
       want systemd to reload the configuration file of a unit, use the
       daemon-reload command. In other words: for the example case of
       Apache, this will reload Apache's httpd.conf in the web server,
       not the apache.service systemd unit file.

       This command should not be confused with the daemon-reload
       command.

   daemon-reload
       Reload the systemd manager configuration. This will rerun all
       generators (see systemd.generator(7)), reload all unit files, and
       recreate the entire dependency tree. While the daemon is being
       reloaded, all sockets systemd listens on behalf of user
       configuration will stay accessible.

       This command should not be confused with the reload command.

       In other words: for the example case of Apache, this will reload Apache's httpd.conf in the
       web server, not the apache.service systemd unit file.

       This command should not be confused with the daemon-reload command.
```

`man systemd.service`:

```
ExecReload=
    Commands to execute to trigger a configuration reload in the
    service. This argument takes multiple command lines, following
    the same scheme as described for ExecStart= above. Use of this
    setting is optional. Specifier and environment variable
    substitution is supported here following the same scheme as for
    ExecStart=.

    One additional, special environment variable is set: if known,
    $MAINPID is set to the main process of the daemon, and may be
    used for command lines like the following:

        ExecReload=kill -HUP $MAINPID

    Note however that reloading a daemon by sending a signal (as with
    the example line above) is usually not a good choice, because
    this is an asynchronous operation and hence not suitable to order
    reloads of multiple services against each other. It is strongly
    recommended to set ExecReload= to a command that not only
    triggers a configuration reload of the daemon, but also
    synchronously waits for it to complete. For example, dbus-
    broker(1) uses the following:

        ExecReload=busctl call org.freedesktop.DBus \
               /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus \
               ReloadConfig
```